# Springboot Security hasRole ignored

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to secure some urlpattern of my spring boot application (1.21)
looks like my antMatchers("/report**").**hasRole("REPORT")** is ignored.
i changed the order of my antMatchers but this changed nothing.

e.g. if I browse to anything like localhost:9000/report/books i need to login and it works only with my username password combination, but i did not set the ROLE **REPORT** to my user "user". so i would expect that I am not allowed to visit the report site, but the page is shown.

How do I have to change it that only users with the Role REPORT can visit that url?

**EDIT1** Updated sourcefiles

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");    
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
        return new MyCustomizer();
    }

    private static class MyCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
            factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error/404"));
            factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(Exception.class, "/error/exception"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {    
      registry.addResourceHandler("/error/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.sessionManagement().enableSessionUrlRewriting(false);

        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/report**").hasRole("REPORT")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you used @EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) and .fullyAuthenticated() ? What is your whole configuration ?

Comment: i added all my files and chanced authenticated to fullyauthenticated, but i am still able to visit the page

Comment: have you tried to split path like /main (permit all) and /report (permit report only) then ?

Comment: i added @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") to my @RequestMapping method in my controller and it does what i want partly. I think what was missing is:          .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403") and maybe an AccessDeniedHander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to change the following:

1. change /report** to /report/**
2. add .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
3. Maybe it works without the @Order but i saw it in the spring boot sample
4. (the /error/403 must be mapped to an errorpage)

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.sessionManagement().enableSessionUrlRewriting(false);

        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/report/**").hasRole("REPORT")
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");

    }

    @Override
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN","REPORT");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried your previous configuration with only the antMatcher for report modified?

Comment: None of these helped in my case :/